# Adding a handler for a particular list item in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and that has list item with text, progressbar and image.

I want to add a delay in every list item loader and image only and show the image after progress completes in recycler view adding a delay of 3 sec.

Here is my **adapter**

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView;
    switch (viewType) {
        case USER_HEADER:
            layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user_header, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(layoutView);
        default:
            layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user_info, parent, false);
            return new AppListViewHolder(layoutView, onRecyclerItemClick);

    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return USER_HEADER;
    }
    return USER_ITEM;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (holder.getItemViewType() == USER_HEADER) return;

    final AppListViewModel appListViewModel = appListViewModels.get(position - 1);
    final AppListViewHolder appListViewHolder = (AppListViewHolder) holder;
    if (!appListViewModel.isAppInstalled()) {
        appListViewHolder.textAppLink.setText(appListViewModel.getAppLink());
    } else {
        appListViewHolder.textAppLink.setText("");
    }
    appListViewHolder.textAppName.setText(appListViewModel.getAppName());
    appListViewHolder.itemView.setTag(appListViewModel);

    // TODO I want to add this progressbar and image after every 3 sec. Just like checking the installation after every 3 sec.
    appListViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    appListViewHolder.imageStatus.setImageResource(appListViewModel.isAppInstalled() ? R.drawable.ic_check_green : R.drawable.cancel);
    setAdapterData(holder);
    loaderStatusListner.isLoadingComplete(true);

}

private void setAdapterData(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder){
    this.viewHolder = viewHolder;
}
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getAdapterData(){
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 1 + appListViewModels.size();
}


private static class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

static class AppListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.image_app_status)
    public ImageView imageStatus;
    @BindView(R.id.text_app_name)
    TextView textAppName;
    @BindView(R.id.text_app_link)
    TextView textAppLink;
    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
    public ProgressBar progressBar;


    AppListViewHolder(View view, final OnRecyclerItemClick onRecyclerItemClick) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppListViewModel commonTicketViewModel = (AppListViewModel) v.getTag();
                onRecyclerItemClick.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), commonTicketViewModel);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Loader should keep moving and one by one its visibility gets INVISBLE after 3 sec delay and image change. See the image for more description
[image: see image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by using a `handler` and a state for my `progressabar` and `image` in my `ViewModel` and after my all the data is added in my Fragment.

Added this line after adding the data to adapter:

```
Message message = new Message();
message.arg1 = 0;
message.what = 0;
handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 2000);
```

Then add a Handler to handle the message:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        int position = msg.arg1;
        appListViewModels.get(position).setProgressState("INACTIVE");
        appListViewModels.get(position).setImageState("ACTIVE");
        userListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position + 1);
        if (position < userListAdapter.getItemCount() - 2) {
            appListViewModels.get(position + 1).setProgressState("ACTIVE");
            userListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position + 2);
        }

        if (position < userListAdapter.getItemCount() - 2) {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.arg1 = position + 1;
            message.what = 0;
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 2000);
        } else {
            if (totalActivatedApps == 5) {
                buttonContinue.setEnabled(true);

            } else {
                buttonContinue.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of recycling procedure of `RecyclerView` you can't handle it using a handler only in `ViewHolder`. In this case, by scrolling the list, every `itemView` has changed and points to a new view and by finishing the delay of handler, it may updates a wrong view. So you should keep the time of updates as a field in `AppListViewModel` instances. I mean you should keep `System.currentTimeInMillis() + (i + 1) * 3000` as an update time for each row. Then in view holder class (where you wrote the `TODO`) compare the current time with update time of the row from viewModel instance. If the time is over, then update the views. 
At the end, in your `Fragment` (or `Activity`) which initializes the `Adapter`, try to call `adapter.notifyDatasetChange()` every second.

You can use below class to keep triggering every second:

```
private class SchedulerHandler extends Handler {

    private static final long SCHEDULE_TIME = 1000;
    private static final int MSG_START = 1;

    private SchedulerHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_START:
                // call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_START, SCHEDULE_TIME);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown what=" + msg.what);
        }
    }

    void startScheduling() {
        sendEmptyMessage(SchedulerHandler.MSG_START);
    }

    void stopScheduling() {
        removeMessages(SchedulerHandler.MSG_START);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
SchedulerHandler schedulerHandler = new SchedulerHandler();
schedulerHandler.startScheduling();
```

At the end of updates:

```
schedulerHandler.stopScheduling();
```